# ctrl - ] freezes window?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having some issue with holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and pressing <kbd>]</kbd> few times in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.
Don't ask my why I need to do it, I don't, it's just something I tried pressing.
Each time I do it, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio freezes up.  It doesn't let me scroll, or select text.
I tried same keystrokes in Word (figuring maybe it's a microsoft-shortcut for something), but it just changes font or something of the sort.

Anyone knows what <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> supposed to do in the tool? and why it would freeze up?

Comment: Probably a bug in MSSMS. ctrl-[ locks it up here too.

Comment: @Avdhut Vaidya has a solution that at least worked for me in Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your window freezes on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, just right click on your window in the system tray. i just discovered it.
i actually wanted to close my window, but surprisingly it responded on right click over the task bar window button.

Comment: Just did this my right clicking the popup window that comes up in Windows 7, totally works. Wish I found this 10 minutes ago.

Comment: saved my life. Love you

Comment: Doing a right click on the popup window in Windows 8.1 still working too.

Answer (score 2):

Definately a bug.  I encountered the error copying and pasting column names (which I always surround with []), so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd> and I apparently held the <kbd>crtl</kbd> button down too long.  not sure what it's supposed to do, but definately freezes.  I've submitted to MS - hopefully will be resolved in their new SP...

Comment: Has this been resolved? Anybody found a work around for this? Its has been over an year. I am slowly weeping to death here.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue twice already. In SSMS <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> is supposed to be a shortcut for navigating to the matching *END* statement for a *BEGIN* and in Visual Studio for navigating to the *CLOSING* curly brace for an *OPENING* curly brace and vice-versa.

I have used this many times without fail in SSMS and VS and it has never posed an issue before. It's still working fine on VS. However, on SSMS, it just hangs there for an eternity.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1, SQL Server 2008 R2 is still causing this issue.

If you inadvertently freeze SSMS, move the mouse over the SSMS icon on the task bar. Wait for the preview window to pop up, then mouse over frozen app preview and hover/wait until windows hides all other open windows and just shows the frozen window/app on your desktop. Once it has done this, right click the app preview window. If you then switch back to SSMS, it should no longer be frozen.